# I have to unninstall GRUB

Tags: uninstall, grub-efi, software-uninstall

So I had removed ubuntu from my laptop by formatting the the disk which it was on, but the GRUB isn't gone yet and I can't find the EFI option with cmd as I have formatted disk, help me to remove the grub, please.

Comment: Grub (program code) exists in the `/boot/grub` directory in the Ubuntu partition, so if you've deleted the Ubuntu partition it's already gone.  Grub has a pointer (the MBR of the disk, ie. first record) which will cause *grub rescue* to appear (it's limited in function as it fits in the boot record of 512 bytes)  but that doesn't get deleted; it's replaced by whatever OS you will use instead of Ubuntu (eg. windows has a number of commands to do it, which differ depending on the version of windows in use... but we're not a windows support site, and don't know what OS you have, nor what version)

Comment: Same issue with me. My ubuntu 18.04 somehow not showing desktop but tty. so I wiped the partition with the windows disk management tool. but the grub is still in the boot partition and I am unable to remove it

Comment: This is a problem outside of Ubuntu as you removed it. If you use windows/mac os you need to fix it from windows/mac os = off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows 10, hold shift and click restart in the start menu. Then click Troubleshoot, then click Advanced Options, then click Command Prompt. This will reboot your computer and boot to a prompt asking for an admin password. Enter the admin password, then in the Command Prompt that appears, type:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Then restart, and grub should be gone.